# Height auto increment when window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

### Bellow my code. div height not increasing when resize the window. can any one help me.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    resizeContent();

    $(window).resize(function() {
        $(".js-tile").each(function(){
            var tileHeight = 0; 
           if ($(this).height() > tileheight) { tileheight = $(this).height(); }
        });
        $(".js-tile").height(tileheight);
    });
});
```

Comment: Post you html as well

Comment: You should probably try some basic debugging before asking on SO.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var tileHeight = 0; 
    $(".js-tile").each(function(){
       if ($(this).height() > tileheight) { tileheight = $(this).height(); }
    });
    $(".js-tile").height(tileheight);
});
```

You must define the variable `tileHeight` outside the `.each` function. What is happening to you right now is that `tileHeight` is `undefined` when passed to `height()` (it hasn't been defined in that scope) and so jQuery ignores it (returns the current height of the element)

Answer (score 0):

Your `var tileHeight` cannot be accessed outside the loop. Here is the solution for your problem.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ resizeContent();

$(window).resize(function() {
    $(".js-tile").each(function(){
       var tileHeight = 0; 
       if ($(this).height() > tileheight) { 
          tileheight = $(this).height(); 
          $(this).height(tileheight);
       }
    });
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

this is [var](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) your code is not workign because a typo in the

> var titleHeight as you declar with the upper H but used it as titleheight

solution:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    let tileHeight = 0; 
$(".js-tile").each(function(){
     if ($(this).height() > tileHeight ) { tileHeight = $(this).height(); }
     });
     $(".js-tile").height(tileHeight );
   });
 });
```

Also I suggest to use [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) as it work as is limited in the scope the block